# Link to register with google gives error from my page but not from allauth page

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, django-allauth

I use the allauth module for authenticating users with google.

In the `/accounts/login/` template, provided by allauth, there's a link "`google`" that has an `href="/accounts/google/login/?process=login"`. You can click that link to be authenticated by google.

Me, I create my own template with the **exact same link**

`<a id="google-login" href="/accounts/google/login/?process=login">Google</a>`

When I click my own link, in my template, I get this error:

```
`XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?state=************&response_type=…id=*************************. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1' is therefore not allowed access.`
```

I dont understand why the exact same link works from allauth's tempalte - /accouts/login/ - but not from my template. Its the exact same link with the exact same href.

OKAY, I noticed something important: when i click on the href from the programmers' console, 
it correctly takes me to the proper address. There's no problem. It open a new tab, and correctly connects me to Google.

I decided to leave a diff between the network-info when I'm clicking the allauth html page's link vs the link in my html page: (the first line is me and the second is allauth)

```
Accept:text/html, */*; q=0.01
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8


Referer:http://localhost:8000/static/index.html
Referer:http://localhost:8000/accounts/login/

X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
this line doesnt exist in the request from allauth's html page
```

If someone has any suggestion please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

jenia

Comment: i think this has to do with csrf authentication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is not the correct answer. 
But have you ever tried with [python-social-auth](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth) formerly known as django-social-auth?